# Nearest neighbor of each row in X against all the other rows in X - Matlab

Tags: matlab, knn

Is there a way of using knnsearch matlab funcion and returning 
the nearest neighbor of each row in X against all the other rows in X?
The sort of output that I would like to get is one like the variable dd in the example above:

```
X = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 3 5; 1 2 3; 1 2 3; 4 3 5; 5 2 1; 3 2 1; 3 5 1];

[rows,~] = size(X);

for i = 1:rows
    for j = 1:rows

         d(i,j) = (norm(X(i,:)-X(j,:)));

    end

   d(1:size(d,1)+1:end) = nan;
   [~,dd(i)] = min(d(i,:));

end
```

Comment: Just take the `k=2` nearest neighbours and discard the trivial solution.

Comment: @flawr I think you should add that as an answer.